# How do I upgrade phpMyAdmin on MAMP Pro?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mamp

MAMP Pro is crawling slow, and I suspect it's because of having it outdated. Where does localhost/phpMyAdmin reside?

Comment: It's worth mentioning that adminer is a much better alternative for light-weight local development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

/Library/Application Support/appsolute/phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 2):

phpMyAdmin resides at /Applications/MAMP/bin/phpMyAdmin.

Follow this link to update phpmyadmin for mamp http://blog-en.mamp.info/2013/08/how-to-upgrade-phpmyadmin-in-mamp-mamp.html